# Can't run "meteor mongo" on Meteor in Windows (latest meteor for windows exe bootstrapper)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to run a meteor app for the first time on Windows( using Windows 7 in particular). I am able to successfully run the app but i can't seem to be able to run the command `meteor mongo` in a separate command prompt window. The following error pops up:

> mongo: Meteor isn't running.
>
> This command only works while Meteor is locally. Start your
>   application first.

I have already tried meteor reset. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is possible a misconception about what the `meteor mongo` command does.
It only connects to the mongo instance of a running meteor development process.

So you need to start the meteor app by changing to your app's directory and running 'meteor'. Then on a different console window, change you the same directory and run 'meteor mongo'.

In the image below, when meteor isn't running I get the error you get, but you will note that it says that you have to start your application first. If you do that, and then in another console window it works:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try one of [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) admin UIs for mongo instead. They connect directly to the db, so should overcome whatever problem there is with command line.

Alternatively, you may try a non-standard command line utility, like Cygwin.